# When clicked on a Component, pass the Component itself as a parameter

Tags: angular, typescript, components, sender

The components are generated through an `ngFor`. The same click event handler is bound to all of them. I want to capture the `Component` on whom the user clicked inside the event handler as an argument.

**Template**

```html
<div>
  <app-my-component (click)="pageClicked(<sender>)" *ngFor="let page of pages"></app-my-component>
</div>
```

**Code Behind**

```js
pageClicked(sender: MyComponent): void {
  // sender would be the COMPONENT who called this function.
}
```

*What I have already tried*

- Making the component a template variable by giving it a name `#comp`, I got an empty object
- Using the `this` keyword, `this` in this context is the parent component, generating the smaller components via ngFor
- Sending `$event` as a parameter and finding the component through the `path`, I don't want the html element, I want the entire component and access to it's public Variables and Methods

Eventually after capturing the component, I'll want to set it's `[selected]` Input to true and clear the last selected component, which shouldn't be that hard if I can only get the component and store it in a local variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let page of pages">
    <app-my-component #component (click)="pageClicked(component)"
    </app-my-component>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Yes using a `template reference variable` was the solution, I tried this at first but I guess the project wasn't built yet when I tested it. Thank you for answering though ; )

Answer (score 1):

if you use a template reference variable you pass the whole component,

```
<app-my-component #component (click)="pageClicked(component)"..>
```

if you has an `@OputPut` use this when emitter, but rename the event `(click)`, use e.g. `(onClick)`

```
//your component
@Output()onClick:EventEmitter<MyComponent>=new EventEmitter<MyComponent>()

clickButton(){
   this.onClick.emit(this)
}
```

see a [fool stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-oqbwbp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

**Template Reference Variable**

```html
<div>
  <app-my-component #mycomponent (click)="pageClicked(mycomponent)" *ngFor="let page of pages"></app-my-component>
</div>
```

```js
pageClicked(sender: MyComponent): void {
  // sender.selected is now available
}
```

*unimportant*

I tried this at first, but got an empty object, guess the project wasn't built yet...

I'll keep this here for later reference and for people asking the same question.