In Angular how to give elements of a table unique IDs
In an Angular component I have a table as below, so that on each row there is a mat-select element:
<table mat-table [dataSource]="data">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="template">

    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Column Title</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let n = index;">

      <mat-select [(ngModel)]="value"
        #drop
        placeholder="Select numbers"
        multiple
      >
        <mat-select-trigger *ngIf="drop.value && drop.value.length">
          {{getDropTextBoxValue(drop, n)}}
        </mat-select-trigger>
        
        <mat-option #all (click)="onClick(all, drop)" [value]="null"
        >Select all</mat-option>
        
        <mat-option *ngFor="let num of allNums[n]" 
          [value]="num"  
          (click)="onClick(null, drop, n)"
        >{{num}}</mat-option>

      </mat-select>

    </td>
  </ng-container>
</table>

So we can see that each mat-select is given the same identifier, #drop
How can I make it so that each one has a unique identifier based on it's row (which I have in the variable n) - say for instance something like drop1, drop2, drop3 etc..
And if I do that then how can I refer to these unique identifiers in each of the following lines (i.e. in the below lines what should take the place of each instance of **drop**)?:
<mat-select-trigger *ngIf="**drop**.value && **drop**.value.length">
  {{getDropTextBoxValue(**drop**, n)}}
</mat-select-trigger>

<mat-option #all (click)="onClick(all, **drop**)" [value]="null"
>Select all</mat-option>

<mat-option *ngFor="let num of allNums[n]" [value]="num"
 (click)="onClick(null, **drop**, n)"
></mat-option>


I may be wrong, somehow the actual goal seem like to add select-all functionality.
Here is a good article for it: How to implement toggle all option in Angular Material Select

Please make sure, this code need Material >= 16. there is new feature implemented as select(false). parameter can control emit event or not. And it's standalone component; if you don't need to use standalone component, refer : demo without standalone

Anyway back to your question, this is an answer for you: Conditional duplicate templateref in ng-content with selector.
I tested your first code at top.
It works well with little bit modification.
<!-- template code -->
<mat-select
 [(ngModel)]="selectedNumberList[n]"   <!-- change as array -->
 #drop
 placeholder="{{ 'Select numbers ' + n }}"
 multiple
>
...
<!-- This is a trick template reference
Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67999275/6808408
-->
<ng-container *ngFor="let page of pages">
  <mat-option #all (click)="onClick(all, drop)" [value]="page"
  >{{page}}</mat-option>
</ng-container>
...

// component code
// to prevent all selected value sync in table.
selectedNumberList: number[] = [];  // as-is: value

Note: Looking around onClick(), there is trick to get #all.
And I prepare demo : Angular-material-dev - Mat Select All (forked)
